# How to refresh currrent frame of GPUImageMovie?

Tags: ios, image-processing, gpuimage

I used AVPlayer and GPUImageMovie to control the playback of movie file while applying filter as below:

```
NSURL *mediaURL = ...
AVPlayer *mainPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:mediaUrl];
[mainPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

GPUImageMovie *currentMovieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
GPUImageFilter *filter = <a filter>;
GPUImageView *videoView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWith...];
[currentMovieFile addTarget:filter];
[filter addTarget:videoView];
[currentMovieFile startProcessing];
[mainPlayer play];
```

Everything worked until I paused the playback and and changed the filter:

```
[mainPlayer pause];
[filter removeTarget:videoView];
[currentMovieFile removeTarget:filter];
filter = <new filter>;
[currentMovieFile addTarget:filter];
[filter addTarget:videoView];
```

I need the videoView to be updated with new filter while the playback was already paused. I tried to play movie player and pause again but somtimes it did'nt work. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a tricky solution.

In your player is paused, if you seek playerItem as much as minimal CMTime(such as CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 1000)), then GPUImageFilters render again.
You don't need to worry seeking makes your preview updates because it's really short time.

Please refer to my codes.

```
    let player: AVPlayer
    let time: CMTime = player.currentTime()

    let diffTime = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: time.timescale)
    var seekTime = time + diffTime

    if let endTime = player.duration {
        if seekTime > endTime {
            seekTime = endTime - diffTime
        }
    }

    player.seek(to: seekTime, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero) { success in
        print("seek success \(checkTime), \(success)")
    }
```